# How to print an unsigned char in C?

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to print char as positive value:

```
char ch = 212;
printf("%u", ch);
```

but I get:

```
4294967252
```

How I can get `212` in the output?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Declare your `ch` as

```
unsigned char ch = 212 ;
```

And your printf will work.

Comment: Even with `ch` changed to `unsigned char`, the behavior of the code is not defined by the C standard. This is because the `unsigned char` is promoted to an `int` (in normal C implementations), so an `int` is passed to `printf` for the specifier `%u`. However, `%u` expects an `unsigned int`, so the types do not match, and the C standard does not define the behavior.

Comment: Your comment is incorrect. The C11 standard states that the conversion specifier must be of the same type as the function `argument` itself, not the promoted type. This point is also specifically addressed in the description of the `hh` length modifier: 

"the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to signed char or unsigned char before printing"

Comment: Only worked after explicit cast to ` unsigned int` when passed to `prtinf()`. Adding -std=c11 to the gcc-4.8.4 command to enforce the standard had no effect.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  What exactly does %d tells ? And what does the specifier %u tells ?

Comment: @andrew.punnett: The function argument is the promoted value; it has the type that results from the integer promotions, per C 2011 6.5.2.2 6. In the case of `hh`, yes, the standard tells us that the type before promotion may be a `signed char` or `unsigned char`. It means that the `ch` will still be promoted to an `int`, but the conversion `%hhu` expects that. However, that is not relevant to this situation where `hh` is not present in `printf(%u, ch)`.

Comment: @SurajJain: `%d` is used for printing an `int` argument in decimal. `%u` is used for printing an `unsigned int` argument in decimal.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  if i do unsigned char a =  -2 and signed char a = -1 , would be the underlying bit pattern same , what would it be ?

Answer (score 42):

This is because in this case the `char` type is signed on your system<sup>*</sup>. When this happens, the data gets sign-extended during the default conversions while passing the data to the function with variable number of arguments. Since 212 is greater than 0x80, it's treated as negative, `%u` interprets the number as a large positive number:

```
212 = 0xD4
```

When it is sign-extended, `FF`s are pre-pended to your number, so it becomes

```
0xFFFFFFD4 = 4294967252
```

which is the number that gets printed.

Note that this behavior is specific to your implementation. According to C99 specification, all `char` types are promoted to (signed) `int`, because an `int` can represent all values of a `char`, signed or unsigned:

> 6.1.1.2: If an `int` can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`.

This results in passing an `int` to a format specifier `%u`, which expects an `unsigned int`.

To avoid undefined behavior in your program, add explicit type casts as follows:

```
unsigned char ch = (unsigned char)212;
printf("%u", (unsigned int)ch);
```

---

<sup>*</sup> In general, the standard leaves the signedness of `char` up to the implementation. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054941/335858) for more details.

Comment: This answer is muddled and inaccurate. The sentences about sign extension and treating 212 are presented without context, failing to explain where they apply (the earlier sentence applies to a later operation, integer promotion of the `char` when it is used as an argument, while the later sentence applies to an earlier operation, initialization of the `char` with an `int`).

Comment: The statement that 212 is treated as negative because it is greater than 0x80 is false. First, initializing a signed `char` with 212 causes integer overflow in most C implementations, so the behavior is undefined. In many C implementations, this results in truncation of the two’s complement representation of 212 to eight bits, which causes the bits to be interpreted as a negative value because the 0x80 bit is set, not because the initial value is greater than 0x80 (counterexamples include 0x80 and 0x100).

Comment: After the initialization of the `char`, it is used as an argument to `printf`. The integer promotions are performed, resulting in a negative `int` being passed to `printf`. Again, many C implementations use two’s complement, so a sign extension is performed, as this answer says. Converting the value to `unsigned` at this point would yield a large positive number. However, this answer fails to explain that the actual behavior is undefined by the C standard because an `int` is being passed for a specifier of `%u`, which expects an `unsigned int`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for your comments! I missed the mismatch between the argument and the format specifier. This is now fixed.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `char` isn’t guaranteed to fit in type `int` since `char` may have been defined to the same behavior as `unsigned char`. Only an integer of the same signedness but smaller integer conversion rank is guaranteed to have a range of values that is a subrange of the range of values of the other type (**section 6.2.5** paragraph 8 of the C99 standard). Therefore, `unsigned char` could theoretically have a range as wide as `unsigned int` due to its signedness and the integer conversion ranks.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the magnitudes of maximum and minimum values of integer types are never larger than the `unsigned` maximum value of the respective type, so all `char` values can therefore fit in an `unsigned int`.

Comment: My last comment only applies to character types since `unsigned char` explicitly has no padding bits (**section 6.2.6.2** paragraph 1) and `signed char` occupies the same storage as a `char` (**section 6.2.5** paragraph 5) which may be represented by an `unsigned char`. Since a `signed char` must have one bit dedicated as the "sign bit" all `signed char` values can be converted to `unsigned char` and back without loss. So all `char` values can be converted to `unsigned int`; though you may not be able to differentiate  between true positive values and negative values cast to `unsigned`.

Comment: If I have something like this `int x = 1234` and `char *y = &x` . Binary representation of `1234 ` is `00000000 00000000 00000100 11010010` . My machine is little endian so it reverses it and store in memory `11010010 00000100 00000000 00000000` LSB comes first. Now Main Part . if i use `printf("%d" , *p)`. `printf` will read first byte `11010010`only the output is `-46` but `11010010` is `210` so why does it print `-46` . I am really confused i guess some char to integer promotion is doing something but i don't know. What Is Happening?

Comment: @SurajJain please ask a question instead of commenting on an answer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I have been restricted to write a question . That is why i am asking here. The ban will be lifted much later.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight What Do You Mean By It is treated as nagative ?

Answer (score 24):

There are two bugs in this code. First, in most C implementations with signed `char`, there is a problem in `char ch = 212` because 212 does not fit in an 8-bit signed `char`, and the C standard does not fully define the behavior (it requires the implementation to define the behavior). It should instead be:

```
unsigned char ch = 212;
```

Second, in `printf("%u",ch)`, `ch` will be promoted to an `int` in normal C implementations. However, the `%u` specifier expects an `unsigned int`, and the C standard does not define behavior when the wrong type is passed. It should instead be:

```
printf("%hhu", ch);
```

(For `%hhu`, `printf` expects an `unsigned char` that has, in normal C implementations, been promoted to `int`.)

Comment: I would suggest to use static_cast instead of old style cast

Comment: @ShitalShah: The question is tagged with C, not C++. C does not have a static_cast operator.

Comment: Ah.. didn't see that.

Comment: What version of C support 'hh' modifier?

Comment: @CloudCho: The `hh` modifier has been in the C standard since 1999.

Answer (score 2):

In case you cannot change the declaration for whatever reason, you can do:

```
char ch = 212;
printf("%d", (unsigned char) ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

The range of char is 127 to -128. If you assign 212, ch stores -44 (212-128-128) not 212.So if you try to print a negative number as unsigned you get **(MAX value of unsigned int)-abs(number)** which in this case is 4294967252

So if you want to store 212 as it is in ch the only thing you can do is declare ch as

```
unsigned char ch;
```

now the range of ch is 0 to 255.

Comment: "THe range of char is 127 to -128." -- No, the range is implementation-defined.

Comment: I mean what I said ... it was plenty clear. A char isn't even necessarily 8 bits, let along necessarily signed.

Comment: This answer is blatantly wrong. The range of char *does* vary, it is commonly unsigned 8 bits on ARM platforms.

Answer (score -1):

Because `char` is by default `signed` declared that means the range of the variable is

> -127 to +127>

your value is overflowed. To get the desired value you have to declared the `unsigned` modifier. the modifier's (`unsigned`) range is:

```
 0 to 255
```

to get the the range of any data type follow the process `2^bit` example `char`is 8 bit length to get its range just `2 ^(power) 8`.

Comment: "Because char is by default signed declared..."  

This is not correct: a `char` is **not** signed by default. The standard says (sec 6.2.5, "Types"): "The implementation shall define `char` to have the same range,
representation, and behavior as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`", and there is no mention of a "default". Whether a `char` is signed or unsigned is simply left to the implementation to decide.