# Which integral promotions do take place when printing a char?

Tags: c, printf, undefined-behavior, variadic-functions, integer-promotion

I recently read that

```
unsigned char x=1;
printf("%u",x);
```

invokes undefined behaviour since due to the format specifier %u, printf expects an unsigned int. But still I would like to understand what is going on in this example.

I think that the integral promotion rules apply with the expression `printf("%u",x)` 
and the value represented by `x`.

> A.6.1 Integral Promotion
>
> A character, a short integer, or an integer bit-field, all either signed or not, or an
>   object of enumeration type, may be used in an expression wherever an integer may be used.
>   If an int can represent all the values of the original type, then the value is converted
>   to int; otherwise the value is converted to unsigned int. This process is called integral
>   promotion.

What does "may be used" mean here? Does it mean 'is syntactically correct' or 'is defined behaviour'?

And how is x promoted in this example? I have read that it is promoted to an int, but if `printf("%u", (int x))` is still undefined behaviour then I don't really understand why...

Comment: I think the behavior is indeed defined, for the very reasons you mention.

Comment: [Recommended viewing](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-7-of-n)

Comment: @luserdroog: So you think the "may be used" means that the behaviour should be defined? Or am I missing your point?

Comment: @lee77 Yes. You are correct. "may be used" means it *is* allowed. It is guaranteed by the standard to work correctly. Good job thinking critically. Where did you find the claim that it was undefined?

Comment: @luser droog: I found it in the penultimate answer to a question on stackoverflow (scroll down a little):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736497/print-unsigned-char-in-c

Comment: Ah. What he says is true if it's just `char` and the implementation is implicitly *signed*. Here you say `unsigned char` so it's all within range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `printf` uses a variable argument list, the integer promotions are applied to its integer arguments. In any normal C implementation, the integer promotions convert an `unsigned char` to an `int`. Then you are formatting an `int` With a specifier for `unsigned int`, so the behavior is undefined.

There is no conflict between saying that a character may be used where an integer may be used and the fact that your statement has behavior not defined by the C standard. Although you may use a character in place of an integer, the rules about what may be printed with `%u` still apply. If using a character results in an integer appropriate for the specifier, the behavior is defined. If using a character results in an integer inappropriate for the specifier, the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Discussion elsewhere on Stack Overflow concluded that an exotic C implementation might in theory conform to the C standard while having `char` types (plain, signed, and unsigned) as wide as `int` types. In such an implementation, and `int` could not represent all values of an `unsigned char`, so an `unsigned char` would have to be promoted to an `unsigned int`. However, such an implementation would be exotic and troublesome (notably with handling EOF), and you may ignore it in practice.

Comment: So there are two steps: First, the integer promotion takes place since x represents an integer and printf uses a variable argument list. Now there are two possibilities: 
1) int cannot represent all the values that an unsigned char can (which would be rather exotic). Then x is promoted to an unsigned int, which is defined. 
2) int can represent all the values that an unsigned char can, so x is promoted to an int. In this case, wouldn't there be (within printf, while resolving the va_arg macro) a definition `unsigned int <some variable name> = <value of x>`? Which would be defined as well?

Comment: FYI, the "discussion elsewhere on SO" is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664100/does-printfx-1-invoke-undefined-behavior

Comment: @lee77: No, there is not necessarily any such assignment. When the `printf` implementation sees the `%u` specifier, it will attempt to get the bytes for an `unsigned int` argument. The means by which it does that are up to the implementation. It does not need to be through a C assignment expression. It can be pure assembly or machine language. The only rule you can rely on is this: If you use an `unsigned int` specifier, you must pass an `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Eric: Okay, now I understand. Thanks a lot for making things clear.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Aren't `int` and `unsigned int` guaranteed to be layout-compatible?

Comment: @KerrekSB: They are not guaranteed to be passed in the same place when a function is called. (C 2011 [N1570] 6.9.1 9: “The layout of the storage for parameters is unspecified.”) And you are not guaranteed that the optimizer will not recognize that the behavior is undefined and will respond by eliminating the code or substituting whatever it finds convenient. It is unlikely a normal C implementation would pass `int` and `unsigned int` differently, but the optimizer is less predictable.

Comment: @KerrekSB: There was a question yesterday asking about `1 << -1`, so I compiled `#include <stdio.h>`, `int main(void) { printf("%d.\n", 1 << -1); return 0; }` with Apple clang 5.0 for x86_64 with -O3 and looked at the assembly. Guess what clang put in the register for the second `printf` argument, `%rsi`? Nothing! The assembly did nothing at all with the register. The optimizer recognized the expression was undefined and simply generated no code whatsoever for it.

Comment: For the same reason, the line `printf("%u",1)` yields undefined behaviour: 1 is promoted to an int (since int can always represent 1), so the situation is as before. Or am I missing something here?
It's really astonishing how easy it is to produce undefined behaviour. In future I will code it like this:
`printf("%u", (unsigned int)1)`

Comment: @lee77: That is correct. The ease of encountering undefined behavior in certain situations is a deficiency of the language.

Comment: Out of curiosity, has there ever actually been any production compiler where neither `int` nor `unsigned int` had any padding bits, where `int` was passed in a fashion sufficiently different from `unsigned int` that `%X` wouldn't "naturally" work?  If not, is there any reason why the Standard shouldn't define `%X` to be usable on either `int` or `unsigned int`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The case of `signed int` vs `unsigned int` mismatch in varargs is specifically permitted: "If there is no actual next argument, or if type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undeﬁned, except for the following cases:
— **one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer
type, and the value is representable in both types;**
— one type is pointer to void and the other is a pointer to a character type."

Answer (score 1):

*If* your platform's `int` can represent all values than an `unsigned char` can, then the promotion is to `int`, otherwise to `unsigned int`. So it depends on your platform.

As to "why", that's because you're passing `x` as a variable argument, and the rules of variable arguments say that the standard promotions take place (presumably so as to simplify the implementation).

Comment: So you say that "may be used" in the above context means 'is syntactically correct'? Or does it have a different meaning?

Comment: The promotion is platform-dependent, the legality is not.

Answer (score 1):

Since `printf` uses a variable argument list, it will be unpacked via `va_arg`.  C++ refers to the C standard for `va_arg` rules.  The C99 Standard says the following:

> The `va_arg` macro expands to an expression that has the speciﬁed type and the value of the next argument in the call. The parameter `ap` shall have been initialized by the `va_start` or `va_copy` macro (without an intervening invocation of the `va_end` macro for the same `ap`). Each invocation of the `va_arg` macro modifies `ap` so that the values of successive arguments are returned in turn. The parameter *type* shall be a type name specified such that the type of a pointer to an object that has the specified type can be obtained simply by postfixing a `*` to *type*. If there is no actual next argument, or if *type* is not compatible with **the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions)**, the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases:
>
> - one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;
> - one type is pointer to void and the other is a pointer to a character type.

Clearly, integer promotions are taken into account when determining whether the actual and expected type match.  And signed vs unsigned mismatch is covered by the first bullet point.

Since `x = 1` is certainly a value representable by `unsigned int`, and promotion of `unsigned char` generates either `signed int` (if `INT_MAX >= UCHAR_MAX`) or `unsigned int` (if `INT_MAX < UCHAR_MAX`), this is perfectly legal.