# I have used `unsigned char` type in order to give me data range up to 255, but not happen

Tags: c, date-range

I Have a simple code to convert from decimal to binary as follow

```
unsigned char number= 150, reminder=0;
while(number > 0){
   printf("number=%d, ", number);
   reminder = number % 2;
   number /= 2;
   printf("reminder=%d\n", reminder);
}
printf("\n");
```

the problem is when I input a decimal number greater than 127, gives me a binary number represent a negative number.

How gave me a negative number and I have used `unsigned char` not `char` only ?

([online example](http://ideone.com/2q4RKF))

Note: I'm using visual studio 2010.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/2q4RKF)?

Comment: @Lion King  I am using visual studio 2012, but i cann't reproduce it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand you, what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

for `printf` use `%u` instead of `%d`

`%d` is for signed and `%u` is for unsigned number printing.

Comment: I do it, but in 8 bit give me a negative number, but in 16 bit give me the correct number.
why in 8 Bit doesn't need to gives me the correct number?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the following:

```
   printf("reminder=%u\n", (unsigned int)reminder);
```

Does that work for you? For an explanation of why, see the dicussions on this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736497/print-unsigned-char-in-c).

Comment: +1, but the explicit cast to unsigned int is unnecessay, no? `printf` already takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

basically a char is 8 bit long(1 BYTE) and it can hold -128 to 127 value for a signed char and 0 to 255 value for unsigned char ...and in any compiler whether it is 16 bit or 32 it only occupies 1 byte.......

now the story behind getting a -ve number is explained below....

since the range of char both signed and unsigned is shown above, whenever the compiler encounters value exceeded from the max, the compiler starts again from the beginning.

Ex: for signed char if value exceeds 127 it returns a -ve number i.e the starting range of signed char. for 128 it reutrns a -128. for 129 - (-127) etc..

same is for unsigned char...

sample pgm :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch1 = 128;
    unsigned char ch2 = 257;
    printf("%d\n %d",ch1,ch2);
    getch();
}
```

o/p : -128
       1

Sample program 2 :

```
#include<stdio.h>

Void main()

{
unsigned char ch;
for(ch=0;ch<=255;ch++)
{
printf("%d-%c",ch,ch);
}
}
```

This program should print the ASCII value and the corresponding characters. But it wont. this program is an indefinite loop. The reason is that ch has been defined as a char. And char cannot take values bigger than +127. Hence when the value of cha is +127 and we perform ch++ It becomes -128 instead of +128. -128 is less than 255, hence the condition gets satisfied. Here onwards ch would take values like -127,-126,-----,-1,0,+1,+2,------,+127,-128,-127 etc.
Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks for that Useful information, but I know that. and in our example I'm using `unsigned char` and it is supposed that the value be up to 255, in my example `unsigned char number= 150`. 150 it does not reach the limit 255, and hence, what the problem?

Comment: Well may be ur compiler has a problem or some thing got corrupted...u check ur code online...www.ideone.com... because when i compiled your code..i got correct output...