# assigning 128 to char variable in c

Tags: c, char, signed

The output comes to be the 32-bit 2's complement of 128 that is 4294967168. How?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a;
    a=128;
    if(a==-128)
    {
        printf("%u\n",a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that 4294967168 is 0xFFFFFF80.  And -128 is 0x80.  And on your platform, `char` is a signed type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print an unsigned char in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736497/how-to-print-an-unsigned-char-in-c)

Comment: 128 doesn't fit in a char if it's a signed 8-bit type. And an `int` should be printed by `%d`, not `%u`

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking why you happen to get the output you happen to get on your particular platform?

Comment: `char` can be either signed or unsigned depending on the system. If your system defines `char` as signed, and your `CHAR_BIT` is 8 bits, then the greatest positive number you can store in `char` is 127.

Comment: Printing a negative `int`(or value converted to an `int`) with `printf("%u\n",a);` is _undefined behavior_.

Comment: @chux you are probably right but just for completeness - what part of the standard says that?

Comment: @4386427 See C11 §6.5.2.2 6 and §7.21.6.1 9

Answer (score 4):

Compiling your code with warnings turned on gives:

```
warning: overflow in conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from '128' to '-128' [-Woverflow]
```

which tell you that the assignment `a=128;` isn't well defined on your plat form.

The standard say:

> 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.
>
> 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; **either the result is implementation-deﬁned or an implementation-deﬁned signal is raised**.

So we can't know what is going on as it depends on your system.

However, if we do some guessing (and note **this is just a guess**):

128 as 8 bit would be 0b1000.0000

so when you call `printf` where you get a conversion to `int` there will be a sign extension like:

```
 0b1000.0000 ==> 0b1111.1111.1111.1111.1111.1111.1000.0000
```

which - printed as unsigned represents the number 4294967168

Comment: Just to add to this answer, in some architectures this `char a = 128` might produce 0, and not -128. There was an old old question on SO, I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence of steps that got you there is something like this:

1. You assign 128 to a `char`.
2. On your implementation, `char` is `signed char` and has a maximum value of 127, so 128 overflows.
3. Your implementation interprets 128 as `0x80`. It uses two’s-complement math, so `(int8_t)0x80` represents `(int8_t)-128`.
4. For historical reasons (relating to the instruction sets of the DEC PDP minicomputers on which C was originally developed), C promotes signed types shorter than `int` to `int` in many contexts, including variadic arguments to functions such as `printf()`, which aren’t bound to a prototype and still use the old argument-promotion rules of K&R C instead.
5. On your implementation, `int` is 32 bits wide and also two’s-complement, so `(int)-128` sign-extends to `0xFFFFFF80`.
6. When you make a call like `printf("%u", x)`, the runtime interprets the `int` argument as an `unsigned int`.
7. As an unsigned 32-bit integer, `0xFFFFFF80` represents 4,294,967,168.
8. The `"%u\n"` format specifier prints this out without commas (or other separators) followed by a newline.

This is all legal, but so are many other possible results.  The code is buggy and not portable.

Make sure you don’t overflow the range of your type!  (Or if that’s unavoidable, overflow for unsigned scalars is defined as modular arithmetic, so it’s better-behaved.)  The workaround here is to use `unsigned char`, which has a range from 0 to (at least) 255, instead of `char`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as I hope you understand, the code you've posted is full of errors, and you would not want to depend on its output.  If you were trying to perform any of these manipulations in a real program, you would want to do so in some other, more well-defined, more portable way.

So I assume you're asking only out of curiosity, and I answer in the same spirit.

Type `char` on your machine is probably a signed 8-bit quantity.  So its range is from -128 to +127.  So +128 won't fit.

When you try to jam the value +128 into a signed 8-bit quantity, you probably end up with the value -128 instead.  And that seems to be what's happening for you, based on the fact that your `if` statement is evidently succeeding.

So next we try to take the value -128 and print it as if it was an `unsigned int`, which on your machine is evidently an 32-bit type.  It can hold numbers in the range 0 to 4294967295, which obviously does not include -128.  But unsigned integers typically behave pretty nicely modulo their range, so if we add 4294967296 to -128 we get 4294967168, which is precisely the number you saw.

Now that we've worked through this, let's resolve in future not to jam numbers that won't fit into `char` variables, or to print signed quantities with the `%u` format specifier.